# Get the max values of different columns with if conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I want to get the maximum value of those values < target value, for each row.

For example, from the dataframe below, each column `date1`, `date2`,...`date6` will take turn to become the `target value`

For each `target value` of each row, I want to get the maximum value of those that are smaller than the `target value`. In case the `target value` is the smallest, it will return the `target value`.

I have a data frame `df` as follows:

```
index   date1      date2      date3     date4       date5      date6 
AA     2019-8-1   2019-1-4   2019-2-3  2019-2-2    2019-5-21  2019-5-14
BB     2019-3-12  2019-10-1  2019-6-1  2019-3-17   2019-7-9   2019-6-12
CC     2019-1-11  2019-3-1   2019-8-1  2019-3-27   2019-1-11  2019-1-7
```

My attempt in case the `target value` is `date1`:

```
date1temp = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    mylist = ['date2','date3','date4','date5','date6']
    max = datetime.datetime(2011,1,1)
    for i in mylist:
        if row[i] < row['date1']
             if row[i] > max:
                  max = row[i]
        else:
             max = row['date1']
    date1temp.append((index,max,row['date1']))

cols = ['index','max','target']
result = pd.DataFrame(date1temp, columns=cols)
```

But the code doesn't give the `result` that I want:

```
index  max       target
AA    2019-8-1   2019-8-1
BB    2019-3-12  2019-3-12
CC    2019-1-11  2019-1-11
```

**Expected output:** I want to get the `result` as following:

```
index  max        target
AA     2019-5-21  2019-8-1
BB     2019-3-12  2019-3-12
CC     2019-1-7   2019-1-11
```

Thank you!

Comment: maybe you should include also pandas tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you have to convert your data to datetime so you can compare as you expected the values:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

then you just have to change the `target` with your desired column:

```
target = 'date1'
target_index = df.columns.tolist().index(target)

def process(row):
    target_value = row[target_index]
    smaller = row[row < target_value]

    # check if there is any smaller
    if not smaller.empty:
        return  smaller.max()

    return target_value



pd.concat([df.agg(process, axis=1), df[target]], axis=1).rename(columns={0:'max', target: 'target'})
```

output:

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Thank you very much for your help! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

The mistake comes within this section:

```
    max = datetime.datetime(2011,1,1)
    for i in mylist:
        if row[i] < row['date1']
             if row[i] > max:
                  max = row[i]
        else:
             max = row['date1']
```

First, you set the maximum `max` to `2011-1-1`, but if any value in your list `mylist` is larger or equal to the date in `date1`, the maximum is set to `date1`, which is wrong. You want the maximum of all values being **smaller** than `date1`!

You just need to leave out the `else` path:

```
    max = datetime.datetime(2011,1,1)
    for i in mylist:
        if row[i] < row['date1']
             if row[i] > max:
                  max = row[i]
```